# I get an XSS error in my CodeIgniter 3 script

Tags: php, codeigniter, xss

I am working on a CodeIgniter application,
On localhost, everything works fine and there is no problem or errors. But , when I uploaded the script to a live server, I received this XSS alert when loading the dashboard of my application.
[image]
I don't know how to resolve the problem. This is my *config.php* file :

```
> $config['base_url'] = 'https://demos.xxxxxxxx.com';
> 
> $config['index_page'] = '';
> 
> 
> $config['uri_protocol']   = 'REQUEST_URI';
> 
> 
> $config['url_suffix'] = '';
> 
> 
> $config['language']   = 'english';
> 
> 
> $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
> 
> 
> $config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
> 
> 
> $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
> 
> 
> $config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;
> 
> 
> $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
> 
> 
> $config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
> 
> $config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
> 
> $config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
> 
> $config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';
> 
> 
> $config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
> 
> 
> $config['log_threshold'] = 0;
> 
> 
> $config['log_path'] = '';
> 
> 
> $config['log_file_extension'] = '';
> 
> 
> $config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;
> 
> 
> $config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
> 
> 
> $config['error_views_path'] = '';
> 
> 
> $config['cache_path'] = '';
> 
> 
> $config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;
> 
> 
> $config['encryption_key'] = '';
> 
> 
> $config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
> 
> $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
> 
> $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
> 
> $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
> 
> //$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
> 
> $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
> 
> $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
> 
> $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
> 
> 
> $config['cookie_prefix']  = '';
> 
> $config['cookie_domain']  = '';
> 
> $config['cookie_path']        = '/';
> 
> $config['cookie_secure']  = FALSE;
> 
> $config['cookie_httponly']    = FALSE;
> 
> 
> $config['standardize_newlines'] = FALSE;
> 
> 
> $config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
> 
> 
> $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
> 
> $config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
> 
> $config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
> 
> $config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
> 
> $config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
> 
> $config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
> 
> 
> 
> $config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
> 
> 
> $config['time_reference'] = 'local';
> 
> 
> $config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
> 
> 
> $config['proxy_ips'] = '';
```

Comment: will you show us the controller of that page? there is probably script in your database you need to sanitize the output to prevent script from running.

Comment: public function index()
  {
   
 $this->load->view('includes/header');
 $this->load->view('includes/navbar');
 $this->load->view('includes/sidebar');
    $this->load->view('dashboard/index');
 $this->load->view('includes/footer');
  }

Comment: view page source and look where is it call the script

Comment: By inspecting the code , I found this issue : 
'Get https;//demos.xxxxxx.com/x  404            home:735
home:7 Error: alert was called
    at window.alert (home:5)
    at HTMLImageElement.onerror (home:735)
window.alert @ home:7
onerror @ home:735'

Comment: The problem that in Xampp there is no alert. the alert appears only on live server.
And I tested it with both browsers Chrome and Microsoft Edge , same thing, the alert appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution for the error.
The problem was a data passed by POST method without being sanitized and by chance, some data entered contained coding tags.
I reviewed all my code to sanitize the data passed by forms, and it is working fine now.
I removed all codes like `$_POST['postedvalue']`
and modify it to `$this->input->post('postedvalue');` 
I check also the **config.php** file and set `$config['global_xss_filtering']` to `TRUE`.
Thank you @Arvin for your help